# Would you recommend an alternative for 文档 as a file-extension?

Tags: word-choice, word-requests

Suppose that someone was creating a file browser application intended for people in China.

This particular file-browser is designed to translate English abbreviations into 现代标准汉语.

---

## Example

| INPUT | OUTPUT |
| --- | --- |
| `my_resume.doc` | `my_resume.文档` |

Is 文档 a reasonable choice for `doc`?

The string `doc` is a standard abbreviation of the English word "[document](https://www.youdao.com/result?word=document&lang=en)".

I feel like the word 文档 is intended for small short passages of text.

However...

> - a `.doc` can be 1 page long.
> - a `.doc` can be 2 pages long.
> - a `.doc` can be 100 pages long.
> - a `.doc` can be any number of pages in length, depending on how much text people want to read.

In your opinion, what is better than `文档`  for the abbreviation `doc` inside of file-name such as `my_resume.doc`?

Comment: If you really want to do this, 文档 is enough. However, What's the reason of doing this? The thing seems absurd to me.

Comment: File extensions are phasing out. Windows have been trying to hide file extensions for years. Which, in typical Microsoft fashion, left a wide open gap for milicious exploitations. But it's another story. Linux, for the most part, doesn't rely on file extensions to see what do do with files.

Comment: extension is part of the Name. Do not translate names. File browsers often have a dedicated column showing the Type of the file. Try translate that.

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't translate that. Chinese people recognize .doc, .ppt, etc. They are more of symbols than words. If you translate, they won't know what you are referring to.

A similar example is CPU. Even though the Chinese for it is 中央处理单元, few people would understand the Chinese translation as it is too technical. But if you write CPU, they would understand immediately.

Answer (score 0):

See 软件工程-中英对照-术语表
[https://people.ubuntu.com/~happyaron/l10n/%E8%BD%AF%E4%BB%B6%E5%B7%A5%E7%A8%8B%E4%B8%AD%E8%8B%B1%E5%AF%B9%E7%85%A7%E6%9C%AF%E8%AF%AD%E8%A1%A8-old.html#D](https://people.ubuntu.com/%7Ehappyaron/l10n/%E8%BD%AF%E4%BB%B6%E5%B7%A5%E7%A8%8B%E4%B8%AD%E8%8B%B1%E5%AF%B9%E7%85%A7%E6%9C%AF%E8%AF%AD%E8%A1%A8-old.html#D)

document - 文档
文档是用于在纸张或在暗喻为纸张的介质上表示的一个信息集合。

Also see:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document

A document is a written, drawn, presented, or memorialized representation of thought, often the manifestation of non-fictional, as well as fictional, content.

In my opinion, it is not generally true that the word 文档 is intended for small short passages of text.

In computer-related technology terms, a FILE (文件) is a resource for recording data (storing and accessing data) on a computer storage device (the hardware). It is more about the organization of the information. While a DOCUMENT (文档) is more about the contents of the information.

Answer (score 0):

If doc is 文档，what is docx?

No need to translate them.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, most Chinese had known `.doc` means 文档, translating is not required.

If you really want to translate it, 文档 is the best & offical translation of `.doc` `.docx`.

Tip: For seniors here, 文档 can be any files on the computers as well.